# Add-in button shows error in office online server

Tags: ms-wopi, office-online-server

I have opened the add-in button in my office online server but when I push it, there shows an error "Sorry, there is an problem" in Chinese.

I typed the code to open the add-in button:

Set-OfficeWebAppsFarm -OfficeAddinEnabled：$true

and have set the wopi server "AllowExternalMarketplace" to true.

But it still shows the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by update the OOS to the latest version. Hope this answer can help other developers.